# Dropping foreign keys in Alembic downgrade?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

So I have created a number of tables in my database using an Alembic migration, each has an index and one or two foreign keys.

My upgrade method works fine, executes and creates the tables.

My downgrade method fails, after I drop my indexes and then drop my tables. I believe I also have to drop my foreign keys first? However I can't figure out how to drop foreign keys from the Alembic Documentation.

**Downgrade method:**

```
def downgrade():
    # Drop Indexes
    op.drop_index('ix_charge_id')
    op.drop_index('ix_statutory_provision_id')
    op.drop_index('ix_originating_authority_id')

    # Drop Tables
    op.drop_table('charge')
    op.drop_table('statutory_provision')
    op.drop_table('originating_authority')
```

Each of these three tables has a foreign key, so how do I go about dropping these first?

TYIA.

Comment: Use [drop_constraint](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.drop_constraint) to drop the foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You just need to call drop constrain.  So in your upgrade method you might have the following:

```
op.create_foreign_key(u'my_fkey', 'table1', 'table2', ['table2_id'], ['id'])
```

Then in your downgrade method you just need to have

```
op.drop_constraint(u'my_fkey', 'table1', type_='foreignkey')
```

One thing to watch for is that you assign a name when you create the foreign key, or known exactly the naming convention that will be used by the database.  When you drop the constraint you need to specify the exact name being used.

One last thing which might help and save you time is to use the auto revision function of alembic.  I find this saves a lot of the heavy lifting, and then I can just tweak the scripts if I need to.

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m <message>
```

Check out http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/autogenerate.html for more information about the autogenerate, but it really is a time saver.

Comment: Any way to recover from my previous version *not* having a name for the foreign key?

Comment: @remram If you didn't assign one then the database engine should have assigned one automatically for you.  You need to find out what this is and then update the alembic script to use that value.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not the case, apparently, if using SQLite. In that case there's a workaround in Alembic, documented here: https://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/batch.html#dropping-unnamed-or-named-foreign-key-constraints

Comment: to view the name of the constraint use sql https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-see-foreign-key-relationship-of-a-table.html

Comment: @Mr-F From your example, it seems like `table2.table2_id` references `table1.id`, correct? If so, shouldn't the `drop_constraint` call be on `table2` instead of `table1`?

Comment: @SunnyPro No `table1` has a reference to `table2` using the standard naming convention of `<table>_<column>`.  So in this case the local table `table1` has a column called `table2_id` which is the key in `table2`.    I believe unless I misunderstood the documentation the parameters were: local table, target table, local column, target column.  Of course if I'm wrong then I'll correct the above.

Comment: In my case alembic had correctly created the drop_constraint command, but added it in the wrong order

Comment: After adding FK, if we do show create table table_name, we see  
````
KEY `meeting_id` (`meeting_id`),<br/>
CONSTRAINT `meeting_participants_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meeting_id`) REFERENCES `meeting_infos` (`meeting_info_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE  
````
but after drop_constraint from alembic, i see only below is deleted but first like KEY is remained like that  
````
CONSTRAINT `meeting_participants_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meeting_id`) REFERENCES `meeting_infos` (`meeting_info_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,  
````
should we try anything other than drop constraint